# Keep dom after leaving page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, dom

If I click this button several times and leave the page (google search) then hit back on my browser
1) Chrome resets the DOM so it looks like the page has been refreshed
2) Firefox keeps the DOM but F5 will put it back to its initial state as expected

I'd like the firefox behavior in chrome. Is there a way to do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<body>
Top
<button id="a">aaa</button>
<div id="b"><div>data</div></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#a').click(function(){
    $('#b').append('<div>data</div>');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can type

```
about:config
```

in the adress bar and search for

```
"browser.cache.check_doc_frequency"
```

and change it to `1` , that means it reloads every time

Comment: sorry, misunderstood you question this is how it would work in firefox